# Why my message from the annotation is not displayed?

Tags: spring-boot, annotations, thymeleaf

I made a Custom Annotation for tow localtimes the annotation works but I have a problem. The message which I set in the annotation is not displayed.
Does anyone have any idea? thank you in advance for the advice.

this is @Annotation
The default message is: "The End date should be after the starting 
date." ;

```
import java.lang.annotation.*;
import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;
@Target( {ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE, ElementType.TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = { ValidAfterDateValidator.class })
@Documented
public @interface ValidAfterDate {


    String message() default "The End date should be after the starting 
date." ;

    Class<?>[] groups() default { };

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };
}
```

This is my validator:

```
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;


public class ValidAfterDateValidator implements 
ConstraintValidator<ValidAfterDate, Horaire> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(ValidAfterDate constraintAnnotation) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Horaire horaire, ConstraintValidatorContext 
     context) {
        if (horaire == null) {
            return true;
        }

        return horaire.getHeureDebut().isBefore(horaire.getHeureFin());
    }
}
```

This is my @entity:

```
@ValidAfterDate
@Component
@Entity(name="horaire")
public class Horaire {


@Id @GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "id_horaire")
private Integer id;
@NotNull
@Column(name = "heure_debut")
private LocalTime heureDebut;


@NotNull
@Column(name = "heure_fin")
private LocalTime heureFin;
```

Comment: which message you get

Comment: I have no message...

Comment: no validation erorr message?

Comment: is there called isValid method?